# SMOTE for regression on unbalanced features

Tags: python, regression, feature-selection, imbalanced-data, smote

I am working on a **regression model**, with numerical features and target.

```
y : the weight of wastes collected in recycling bins
Xi : features about demography or urban elements around, or appearance of the bin
```

I noticed that my features that seems to have no impact on the target were also almost the same than the **features that are unbalanced** in the dataset.

```
i.e : "type of bin" -> 66 are buried vs 752 over the ground
*(nb : I used 0/1 for having numerical data)*
```

I would look **whether these features have more impact when using over-sampling**.

I first tried an artisanal way : duplicating data of the minority class.

```
i.e : I duplicated 5 times the 66 bins that are buried
```

For some features, the coefficients of linear regression were significantly higher, but neither feature importance of random forest.

**I would precise my results by using SMOTE, in order to conclude whether these features have an impact on the target.**

I found that we can use SMOTE for regression with smogn or resreg packages.

**But I didn't found how to use it on features** (not on the target : imbalancing is here for features).

Do you know a way to solve it ? (I mean : do you know if I can change a parameter of [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html#imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE) , or use another function, to act on features and not on the target ?)

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempt? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output, so that we can understand how to help

Comment: Ok sorry, I will try to precise even if my issue is that I don't find what to try

Comment: Is it clearer now ?